# How can I randomize search results in Views?

Tags: views

It seems like the simple answer to this issue would be to select **Global:Random** from the Sort Criteria, but choosing this results in a selection of **Global: Random (asc)** -- the asc being ascending.

And indeed the results are displayed as ascending instead of random.

How can this be corrected?

Comment: Global:Random is the only sort criterion applied.

Answer (score 3):

Results are displaying in ascending order because you may have another sort criteria present above **Global: Random (asc)** like say **Content: Post date (desc)**.

**Solution:** Move **Global: Random (asc)** sort criteria to top. Surely it will work.

> Note: If you have more than one sort criteria lets say 3, then results
>   first get sorted with first criteria then with second and then with
>   third.

Comment: Right.  That seems like it would be a problem, but Global:Random is the only sort criterion applied.  Could it be that Search Api/Facets is affecting the order?

Comment: No I don't think Search Api/Facets is affecting the order.